# nested case statement in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, case

Below is the list of files i've in my current directory:

```
ctc.SNAPSHOT-1.0.1-abc.gz
ctc.SNAPSHOT-2.0.1-bcd.gz
ApprovedList.A
ApprovedList.B

cat ApprovedList.A
BC
DEF
```

I want to pass 3 parameters to the script,but i guess the script is unable to read the variable : `$num1`.

Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$#" in
    0|1|2)
        echo "Correct Usage: $0 A/B/C <rec_name>/ALL <version_number>."
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

ops () {
    echo $line
}

num1=$(for i in *gz; do num=$(echo $i|sed -E -n 's/ctc.*\-(.*)\-.*/\1/p'); echo $num; done)

while read -r line
do
    case "$1" in
        A|B|C)case "$2" in
            $line|ALL)case "$3" in
            $num1)ops;;
        esac;;
esac;;
esac
done < /home/us3r/ApprovedList."$1"
```

When i execute the script, it gives no output.

Execution:  `./script.sh A ALL 1.0.1`

Expected output:

```
BC
DEF
```

I have tried the above code using multiple `if` conditions and it's working, i just wanted to make my code more readable and compact ,so i thought of using `case` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Below is the list of files i've in my current directory:
>
> ```
> ctc.SNAPSHOT-1.0.1-abc.gz
> ctc.SNAPSHOT-2.0.1-bcd.gz
>
> num1=$(for i in *gz; do num=$(echo $i|sed -E -n 's/ctc.*\-(.*)\-.*/\1/p'); echo $num; done)
> ```

This will set `num1` to `1.0.1 2.0.1`

> Execution: `./script.sh A ALL 1.0.1`
>
> ```
> $line|ALL)case "$3" in
>             $num1)ops;;
>         esac;;
> ```

And this will not match it, since `$3` is `1.0.1`

Comment: Okay, any way to make that correct?

Comment: make it correct? you'll have to rewrite the whole script into something much more simple. Try reversing the `$num1` and `$3` though: `...ALL) case $num1 in *"$3"*)ops;;` (don't omit the `*`s!).

Comment: Thanks :). i tried as suggested by you, it worked...